# Airflow PythonOperator - decide which task will be next - based on the status of previous tasks

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm not sure if this question should be here/on meta/exchange (let me know and I'll move it)

I was wondering if there is a way to make DAG (using python) in airflow using the `PythonOperator` (or other operator that is suitable to airflow 1.0 on Docker) and in the `python_callable` decide which task will be called next, it will be based on the previous tasks status.

I can already get all of the statuses of all of the tasks, so the thing I'm wondering is how to do that the based on the back tasks statuses it will decide to which task to go next.

I've searched the web for some time now and I didn't find anything helpful too much.

> I'm using airflow version of 1.1 on Docker

I dont have a code example because that's what I'm trying to figure out, but let's say this is the basic idea:

```
TaskA >> TaskB
if TaskB >= -1 Go to TaskNegative
if TaskB == 0 go to TaskZero
if TaskB <= 1 go to TaskPositive
if TaskB == fail/null go to TaskFail
if TaskA == fail/null go to TaskC (TaskC will do the same as A did with B but with TaskD for example)
```

That is a very basic idea of what I'll need to implement (will be much more options, more condition etc...) which everything I can do using python code logic, but I'll need a way to supply that into an operator of some sort (again that works on airflow 1.0 on Docker)

Comment: status of what? do you mean the task status or something that is set in the function you invoke? Please add example so it would be easier to understand what you mean

Comment: As it says in the title, based on the status of previous tasks.
and I tried to give a very basic example of the idea in order to help people understand my meaning

Comment: The title is confusing because Airflow tasks have status (success, failed, upstream_failed, etc) so it seemed that you asked about this but your edit suggest that you actually talk about your python_callable return value. So it's good that I asked for this clarification. In that case Daniel answer is correct - you should use branch operators.

Comment: That is also, based on the status as fail and more also I meant, as you see I added also a fail / null option there :)

Comment: The A in DAG stands for Acyclic. Your request is to create cycle. This is not a DAG (and probably why you are having difficult figuring how to do this). If your use case is cycles then Airflow is not the right tool for that.

Comment: it's not a must but it was an idea, I'll try to implement using your suggestions and will keep you updated :)

Comment: Removing the cycle requirement its a classic case for Branch operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [BranchPythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python/index.html#airflow.operators.python.BranchPythonOperator) is what you're looking for. Similar to the `PythonOperator`, it will take a `python_callable`, but instead it expects the return value to be one or more task IDs. Just make sure all the possible next tasks are set as downstream dependencies of this task. It will run the specified tasks, then skip the rest.

Comment: I've tried the `BranchPythonOperator`, but it does not work on airflow 1.10 on Docker for what I've seen, have you tried it on that version and it worked?

Comment: Please explain what is not working

Comment: I had a problem that the airflow 1.0 (Docker) did not recognize the branch operator, so I thought its something that was added only on a higher version, but I just found the problem and fix it and now the branch operator is working :)

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is using `BranchPythonOperator` as mentioned in the other answer, I just tested a dag in Airflow `1.10.15` and it works fine:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from random import choice

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import BranchPythonOperator, PythonOperator


def t2_process(**context):
    random_choice = choice(["TaskNegative", "TaskZero", "TaskPositive", "fail"])
    print(random_choice)
    if random_choice == "fail":
        raise Exception()
    return random_choice


with DAG(
        "test_branch",
        start_date=datetime(2022, 8, 25),
) as dag:
    T1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="T1",
        python_callable=lambda: print("T1"),
    )
    T2 = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id="T2",
        python_callable=t2_process,
        retries=1,
        retry_delay=timedelta(minutes=1)
    )
    TaskNegative = PythonOperator(
        task_id="TaskNegative",
        python_callable=lambda: print("TaskNegative"),
    )
    TaskZero = PythonOperator(
        task_id="TaskZero",
        python_callable=lambda: print("TaskZero"),
    )
    TaskPositive = PythonOperator(
        task_id="TaskPositive",
        python_callable=lambda: print("TaskPositive"),
    )
    TaskFail = PythonOperator(
        task_id="TaskFail",
        python_callable=lambda: print("TaskFail"),
        trigger_rule="all_failed",
    )
    T1 >> T2 >> [TaskNegative, TaskZero, TaskPositive, TaskFail]
```

I simulated the 4 cases using `random.choice`, you can replace the callable by your processing methods. For the `TaskFail`, the `T2` will retry one time after the first fail, and if it fails again, `TaskFail` will be triggered because of its `trigger_rule`.